# Ban or synonymize [amp]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

[amp](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amp) is a fairly awful tag, some use it in the context of current (amps...[current](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/current) by the way is another useless tag, not to mention [voltage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voltage), [circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circuit), and the like...but we're not here to talk about them) or as shorthand for [amplifier](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amplifier).

Can we either blacklist the tag or synonymize it with [amplifier](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amplifier)?

As of this post there are 8 [amp](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amp) questions that I will dispatch in short order.

Answer (score 9):

Done.

[amp](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amp) is now a synonym for [amplifier](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amplifier)